# Laravel group by and order by, how to solve?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a database called `maintenance` that has a field called `cost`. I now want to get the sum the costs by `month and year` and sort them in descending order by `month and year`. Could someone please help me with that?

Here what I have tried

```
$MaintenanceStats = Maintenance::oldest()
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($val) {
         return Carbon::parse($val->from)->format('F');
     })
     ->take(7);
```

I got this collection object bellow, which works fine. But how can I group them by both month and year and then order them in descending order rather than just grouping by month? Plus, I only need the monthly total cost; I don't need all maintenance records.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1517 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\GeneralController.php:40
  #items: array:5 [▼
    "September" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1452 ▶}
    "July" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1530 ▶}
    "January" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1519 ▶}
    "November" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1520 ▶}
    "December" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1521 ▶}
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to do it with the DB queries, but you'll need a raw query as well:

```
$maintenanceStats = Maintenance::selectRaw("year(`from`) AS year, month(`from`) AS month, sum(cost) AS cost_total")
   ->groupByRaw("year(`from`)")
   ->groupByRaw("month(`from`)")
   ->orderBy('year')
   ->orderBy('month')
   ->get();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help; however, instead of receiving a numeric value for the month, how can I obtain its string value?

Comment: Use `monthname` in the select instead of `month`. ([Time and date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)) I would suggest having both in the select statement, so your orderBy won't try to order the month alphabetically.

Comment: Perfect! One more question: how would I go about obtaining a `collection` similar to the one I posted in the question, where the `month` name serves as the `key`?

Comment: Eloquent/DB queries return a collection, so you can just add `->keyBy('month')` (or whatever you name the monthname in your select) to the end of the query. Just know that if you have multiple months, it's going to get overwritten

Comment: Here's another problem I got, when I select `monthName('from')` and `group by monthName`, same months are grouped without taking the year into account. How do solve that problem?

Comment: Make sure you keep the `groupByRaw("year(\`from\`)")` in there as well

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: I figured out the problem. `keyBy()` method is actually making this grouping. Thanks fo your help.